# Custom CoordinatorLayout behavior

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/view_product_details"/>  // This contains a NestedScrollView

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/indicator"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
              android:gravity="right|bottom"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              app:layout_behavior="utils.CustomBehavior">

            // Some views.. 
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the indicator layout to be shown when the user opens the Activity but it should hide when the user scrolls a bit down.
When the user scrolls back to the top of the page I want it to show again.

So I wrote a custom behavior class:

```
public class CustomBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior {

private int totalY;

public CustomBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof NestedScrollView;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

    totalY += dyConsumed;

    Log.d("Scroll", "Total Y : " + totalY);

    LinearLayout fabMenu = (LinearLayout) child;
    FloatingActionButton wishListButton = (FloatingActionButton) fabMenu.findViewById(R.id.fab_wishlist);
    FloatingActionButton collectionButton = (FloatingActionButton) fabMenu.findViewById(R.id.fab_collection);
    FloatingActionButton tastedButton = (FloatingActionButton) fabMenu.findViewById(R.id.fab_tasted_list);

    if (totalY > 10) {
        wishListButton.hide(true);
        collectionButton.hide(true);
        tastedButton.hide(true);
    } else if (totalY < 10) {
        wishListButton.show(true);
        collectionButton.show(true);
        tastedButton.show(true);
    }
}
}
```

But the adding and subtracting of total Y value is not reliable.
How can I detect that the user has reached the top of the NestedScrollView?

Or is there a better way to implement something like this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Friendly advice: get rid of `findViewById()` inside that method move it inside `onLayoutChild()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following could help - inside `onNestedScroll()`:

Use

```
 if (target instanceof NestedScrollView) {
        final NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) target;
        totalY = nestedScrollView.getScrollY();     
 }
```

In place of

```
totalY += dyConsumed;
```

Comment: Why are they different?